# Reading NSMutableArray from File

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I am trying to read an 2 NSMutableArrays from file. I am saving and loading as such:

SAVE:

```
NSMutableDictionary *saveDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[saveDict setValue:name forKey:@"name"];
[saveDict setValue:last_episodue forKey:@"whereat"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/ShopFile.sav"];
[saveDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

LOAD:

```
        name = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    last_episodue = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/ShopFile.sav"];
    NSDictionary *loadDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    name =            [loadDict valueForKey:@"name"];
    last_episodue=     [loadDict valueForKey:@"whereat"];
```

The variables name and last_episodue have been declared in the header file.

The program compiles and runs, however at runtime when trying to load the file, the LOAD part of the code executes, and when it finishes, the program stops working. This is the debugging information (first part):

```
2012-10-13 12:14:10.801 series[5223:303] -[NSISRestrictedToZeroMarkerVariable copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001900c0
2012-10-13 12:14:10.803 series[5223:303] -[NSISRestrictedToZeroMarkerVariable copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001900c0
2012-10-13 12:14:10.906 series[5223:303] (
```

Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks!

Edit: This is the content of the file where the saving takes place:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
    </array>
    <key>whereat</key>
    <array>
        <string>a</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Have you checked the saved file manually to see if it was saved properly?

Comment: The saved file seems to be OK, proper elements, etc and everything seems in place..

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. What values do name and last_episodue have when you do the save?

Comment: BTW, alloc init'ing name and last_episodue is unnecessary, they will be whatever valueForKey returns.

Comment: @rdelmar updated the question with the contents of the file. Data is just strings. I alloc and init just in case the contents of the read data was empty, so in that case there would be the initialisation part. Not sure if that makes sense.

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense -- you just reassign what name and last_episodue mean when you set them to the value of loadDict's key. This just overrides your initialization. If the key doesn't exist, then name will be nil, not an empty mutable array.  That being said, that's not your problem -- I've never seen that error before, so I don't know what's happening. The only things I can suggest, are to do a "clean" on your project, and see if that helps, or delete that file and run the app again.

Comment: I understand what you mean regarding the init,alloc and will change accordingly. Did try to clean and rebuild the project, as well as delete the file. Still same problem. Strange. I'll probably try some other method of saving then..

Comment: It would probably be instructive to test out your code in a separate test project.  I think you'll find that the error is elsewhere: I was able to run your code by itself without a problem.  You might also try turning on NSZombies.

Comment: @Nate I'll try that and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, since I can't tell without more context what your memory management looks like, but I just had this issue stemming from a variable whose value was not retained properly (we were assigning it using `objc_setAssociatedObject` but passing `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` as the objc_AssociationPolicy). The pointer I held consistently ended up pointing over to an instance of `NSISRestrictedToZeroMarkerVariable`.

Since `NSISRestrictedToZeroMarkerVariable` is not a publicly-exposed class, what you're seeing is most likely the result of a memory overwrite. Set an exception breakpoint in Xcode and check out which line is throwing this error, and then track your memory management for that variable.